# Rename files with path name

Tags: bash, rename

I have some files of type .csv but they are named differently. Ideally, I would like the script to find all files with .csv type and rename file using its path name.

When files are renamed they should be something like this:

```
/home/doc/funds2015/folder xxx/folder 123/Folder xxx/something1.csv
/home/doc/funds2015/folder xxx/folder 123/Folder xxx/something2.csv    
xxx_123_01_01.csv 
xxx_123_02_01.csv
```

Can someone help me restructure this code to do this in one clean loop. I am fairly new to bash.

```
oldpath= "/home/doc/funds2015"

for file in $(find $oldpath -type f -name something1.csv); do
    shortname=${file#$oldpath/}
    newname="${shortname "some reg ex"}"

    if [ -f $newname ]; then
            echo "$newname already exists."
    else
            echo "copy: $file"
            echo "  --> $newname"
            cp $file $newname
    fi
done

for file in $(find $oldpath -type f -name something2.csv); do
    shortname=${file#$oldpath/}
    newname="$oldpath "some reg ex"}"

    if [ -f $newname ]; then
        echo "$newname already exists."
    else
        echo "copy: $file"
        echo "  --> $newname"
        cp $file $newname
    fi
done
```

Comment: Your file paths have two "xxx" bits in them, and you example output has one "xxx" in it. Which "xxx" do you want?

Comment: I only want the first 'xxx' and to append '_01' to the end of all .csv files

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loop.

You can use the command rename, retrieve and reuse any expression with a perl expression.

Here are some examples of such expression :

```
rename -n "s/^.*([0-9]{3}).*$/Clannad_c\$1/" *
rename -n "s/^(.*)c([0-9]{3})\/(.*)$/\$1c\$2\/Clannad_c\$2p\$3/" */*
rename -n "s/(.*)\/(.*)/\$1\/\$1p\$2/" */*
rename -n "s/^.*([0-9]{4}).*$/Hajime\ no\ Ippo_c\$1/" *
rename -n "s/(c[0-9]{3}_p[0-9]{2}.jpg)$/v38_\$1/" Vagabond_v38*/*
```

You can match any part of the path or file name with () and reuse it with $1, $2, ... And with the use of shell expansion, you won't even need to do a loop (*/*).

If I were to stick to something closer to what you tried, I'd use the command find and its option -exec.

Here is an example :

```
find "$sourceDir*v0$volumeNumber*" -type f -name "*.(jpg|png)" -exec zip --quiet -r $newVolume {} +
```

This command find some jpg and png files and zipped them.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought (without the for loop stuff). is there only one file in each folder?
you might check out the *basename* and *dirname* commands. maybe in addition with *tr*.
like:

```
dirname /home/doc/folder12/folder34/file.csv | tr "/" "_"
```

gives you the path (without the filename part)

```
basename /home/doc/folder12/folder34/file.csv
```

gives you the filename only, without the path

so,

```
path_reformatted=$(dirname /home/doc/folder12/folder34/file.csv | tr "/" "_")

filename=$(basename /home/doc/folder12/folder34/file.csv | tr "/" "_")

new_filename=$path_reformatted$filename
mv $old_filename $new_filename
```

that would return a useable filename?